# Web application development on Scala

Tags: scala

I have just learnt Scala and I want to try some web development with it. On Google, one of the frameworks I came across (the only one?) was [Lift](http://liftweb.net/). What is the experience using it?

What can be recommended for web application development with Scala on any other frameworks?

Comment: see [What Scala web-frameworks are available?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1488412/309483)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AFAIK, Lift is the most mature game in town if you want to stick with a Scala based solution, also see http://code.google.com/p/slinky2/. A word to the wise, I have yet to use slinky at all, except for browsing the source, it's very simple in design adhering strongly to request => response model.

Mind you, this is Scala, and so you can use all of Java's existing frameworks. In particular, I'd suggest you look at wicket: http://technically.us/code/x/the-escape-hatch that describes how to combine the two.

Answer (score 28):

I personally recommend you using [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com).

Answer (score 1):

The most used full stack Scala web frameworks are Lift and Play! Take a look at both before you commit. One major difference between the two is Lift is stateful while Play! is stateless, more akin to Rails/Django.

Comment: Lift can be used as stateless too, while using lift as stateful gives you secure and very powerful comet and ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Jsf2 works well.  I guess struts would too.  They aren't Scala per se, but you can use only Scala and the appropriate EL and they work fine.  And those two are much more mature than any of the new frameworks. Communities are bigger, documentation better, etc.