# How would you compare a Scala-based web server with other web frameworks?

Tags: scala, operating-system, webserver

I have read about Scala but have not been able to do **comparative analysis** of other web programming frameworks on the basis of:

- **maintainability** (does the Scala language facilitate the maintainability of such a web framework, compared to, say, a Php-based one?),
- **scalability** (what OS is best adapted for a Scala wab server to be scalable?),
- **compatibility** (Like Php works well with Apache web server and asp.net with IIS., Scala must have some specific web server compatibility),
- and other rational categories.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What do you want to know?

Comment: I want scala advantage over other web languages and also its compatibility with web servers and OS.

Comment: Scala isn't a 'web language' any more than Java or (haha) haskell. Some people use it for web apps, just like some people use Lisp.

Comment: I just tried to change the redaction of this question to make it a "more legitimate one".

Comment: Darn... closed even though I did make the effort to make it a real question...

Comment: @bmargulies: Not quite true. See this presentation: http://goo.gl/cNJI

Comment: @Rahul G: yes! thank you :) Two more votes to go.

Comment: This question is much better worded now, but it is too broad. One could write books comparing different web frameworks available in all languages. It would be a better question if its scope was more restricted. Still, the criteria there is objective, making the question answerable. Perhaps it would be better as a community question, as there is no one "right" answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

The question is better worded now, though still too open for my taste. Still, I'm leaving my original answer as a reference.

**Original Answer**

This question is rather vague, and the non-vague part is duplicated. See ["How many Scala web frameworks are there?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/how-many-scala-web-frameworks-are-there)

Answer (score 2):

An web application framework like **[Lift](http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php/Main_Page)** sums it up nicely:

> And because Lift applications are written in Scala, an elegant new JVM language, you can still use your favorite Java libraries and deploy to your favorite Servlet Container. Use the code you've already written and deploy to the container you've already configured!

So you can use any [Servlet 2.4 engine](http://www.servlets.com/engines/) (e.g., Tomcat 5.5.xx, Jetty 6.0, etc.) you want.
The advantage of Scala itself compared to other language is not as important as the advantage that a web framework ([like Lift or **other Scala-based web frameworks**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/how-many-scala-web-frameworks-are-there)) can offer over other web framework applications (Rails, Django, ...)

Comment: I was about to use PHP for my website so should i carry on or should i use this scala with lift?

Comment: @adi: if you are the only developer, with a good knowledge of Php, and less or few knowledge in Java and Scala, go with Php. But if you have the choice, then it depends of the level of support you need from your web framework to include third-pary libraries. If you need to include Comet for instance (http://alex.dojotoolkit.org/2006/03/comet-low-latency-data-for-the-browser/), then Lift is a very good fit (see the comment at the end of http://java.dzone.com/articles/interview-lift-creator?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign)

Comment: @erlord: you can read it as "the minimum version compatible with servlet 2.4", i.e Jetty6.0 and more.

Comment: @adi. First figure out what you want to do. If you just want to build some "web sites" and can already program in PHP, go ahead and use it. 
If you want to do anything more serious (normally called "web applcations"), Lift and Scala is a great choice.

If you don't know PHP, stay away from it. It is one of the worst languages I have ever seen in widespread use. The words I normally use to describe that piece of mess PHP is, is not acceptable on SO, so I won't comment any further.