# Trying to run sbt on Ubuntu. (Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject)

Tags: scala, sbt

I've tried installing `sbt` to start using Scala version 2.8 in Ubuntu. (I'm currently using version 2.7.)

When I run `sbt` from the terminal I get the following output:

```
$ sbt
Project does not exist, create new project? (y/N/s) y
Name: HelloWorld
Organization: org
Version [1.0]: 
Scala version [2.7.7]: 
sbt version [0.7.4]: 
Getting Scala 2.7.7 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-tools.sbt#boot-scala
 confs: [default]
 2 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (6214kB/279ms)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$.classMissing$1(Provider.scala:71)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$$anonfun$getMissing$1.apply(Provider.scala:72)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$$anonfun$getMissing$1.apply(Provider.scala:72)
 at scala.List.filter(List.scala:859)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$.getMissing(Provider.scala:72)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$initialize.call(Provider.scala:45)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$initialize.call(Provider.scala:32)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:63)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:67)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:67)
 at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
 at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:67)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:45)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:45)
 at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:31)
 at xsbt.boot.Provider$class.$init$(Provider.scala:31)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$ScalaProvider.<init>(Launch.scala:80)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$1.apply(Launch.scala:72)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$1.apply(Launch.scala:72)
 at xsbt.boot.Cache.newEntry(Cache.scala:17)
 at xsbt.boot.Cache.getFromReference(Cache.scala:13)
 at xsbt.boot.Cache.apply(Cache.scala:12)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:73)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:48)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:42)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:42)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:57)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.explicit(Launch.scala:42)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.initialized(Launch.scala:38)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.parsed(Launch.scala:31)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.configured(Launch.scala:21)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
 at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:13)
 at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
 at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:19)
 at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
 at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 ... 62 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add how you defined your `sbt` script, and make sure that jar file is inside the same directory as `sbt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when an incorrect Scala version is used. Since SBT manages Scala on its own, my suggestion is that you *remove* any Scala package you might have installed.

Comment: That worked for me. Now though I can't get myself a nice scala read/eval/print-loop by typing `scala`. Can I easily launch a scala "console" through sbt? (I realize I can do it if I create a project first, but it seems like an overkill just to launch scala)

Comment: @aioobe Try installing Scala by hand, downloading it from scala-lang, and then adding it to the PATH of your home profile. I don't know why Ubuntu's package is causing trouble, but it must be doing something out of the ordinary, since I have no trouble running SBT and having a Scala installed by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Try a restart `sbt` after deleting:

1. `~/.m2/repository`
2. `~/.ivy2/cache`
3. `project/boot`

As described in [sbt troubleshooting](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set your `$SCALA_HOME` environment variable properly?

I saw the [Conky GUI Ubuntu project having a similar issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-856370.html) (bottom of the page, not with sbt directly, but with Scala), and here is the script they are now using to make sure and set all Scala related variables:

(The all script is probably not relevant for your sbt script, but it gives you an idea about setting `$SCALA_HOME`)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

#-----------------------------------#
#             Functions             #
#-----------------------------------#

function copy_variables_file {
    # Copying variables.xml to ~/.conkygui
    if [ ! -d ~/.conkygui ]; then
        mkdir -v ~/.conkygui
    fi
    cp -vu /usr/share/doc/conkygui/variables.xml ~/.conkygui
}

function get_scala_home {
    # check if $SCALA_HOME is set
    if [ -z $SCALA_HOME ]; then
        # try to find it at common locations
        dists=('Fedora' 'Ubuntu')
        paths=('/usr/share/scala' '/usr/share/java')
        for indx in 0 1
        do
            SCALA_HOME=${paths[$indx]}  
            if [ -d $SCALA_HOME ]; then
                break
            fi
            SCALA_HOME=''
        done
    fi

    # check if $SCALA_HOME could be found
    if [ -z $SCALA_HOME ]; then
        echo '$SCALA_HOME is not set'
        exit 2
    else
        echo $SCALA_HOME
        return 0
    fi
}

function get_scala_library_path {
    SCALA_HOME=$1
    scala_library=$SCALA_HOME'/scala-library.jar'
    if [ -f $scala_library ] ; then
        echo $scala_library
        return 0
    fi
    # try with lib folder
    scala_library=$SCALA_HOME'/lib/scala-library.jar'
    if [ -f $scala_library ] ; then
        echo $scala_library
        return 0
    else
        echo 'error: scala-library.jar could not be found';
        exit 1
    fi
}

function get_classpath {
    SCALA_HOME=$1
    # Except for Scala the required libraries come
    # with Conky GUI and are located in the "lib" folder.
    lib_folder='/usr/share/conkygui'
    bsaf=$lib_folder'/lib/bsaf-1.9-RC3.jar'
    vldocking=$lib_folder'/lib/vldocking-3.0.0.jar'
    conkygui=$lib_folder'/conkygui.jar'
    libs=$bsaf':'$vldocking':'$conkygui
    scala_library=`get_scala_library_path $SCALA_HOME`
    classpath=$libs':'$scala_library
    echo $classpath
}

#-------------------------------#
#              RUN              #
#-------------------------------#

copy_variables_file

SCALA_HOME=`get_scala_home`
echo 'SCALA_HOME: '$SCALA_HOME

classpath=`get_classpath $SCALA_HOME`
echo 'CLASSPATH:  '$classpath

# start Conky GUI
java -cp $classpath controllers.ConkyGUI

exit $?
```

Comment: But SBT installs its own Scala. The problem might happen because he _has_ Scala installed, not the other way around.