# (Scala) Creating a Map using for yield {}

Tags: scala, dictionary, for-loop

I was reading about Maps and so I've tried creating one like this:

```
val myMap = for(i <- 0 to 10) yield {
  i.toString->"Number"
}
```

Obviously it would not work. What is the proper way to initialize a map using for loops?

Thanks! ^^

Comment: `(for (i <- 0 to 10) yield { i.toString->"Number" }).toMap`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213992/can-i-use-for-comprehenion-yield-to-create-a-map-in-scala

Comment: Oh, my bad, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `toMap` on the result, like this

```
val myMap = (for(i <- 0 to 10) yield {
  i.toString -> "Number"
}).toMap
```

Answer (score 3):

Using toMap on some collections with tuple returns scala.collection.immutable.Map where the first value is the key and the second one is the value itself.
For the example above you can do the following (and adopt scala style):

```
(1 to 10).map( _.toString -> "Number").toMap
```

Comment: the keys in the question are String not Int

Comment: changed it from: (1 to 10).map( _-> "Number").toMap to (1 to 10).map( _.toString -> "Number").toMap