# Can you tell me any good scala web frameworks?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Scala web-frameworks are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/what-scala-web-frameworks-are-available)

I know there is already a [similar question about scala web frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1488412/35189). What I need though is some suggestion, given the following criteria:

- Good documentation (by which I mean: Readable, understandable, complete)
- Using "well-known" concepts

I've looked at [Play](http://scala.playframework.org/), which looks very promising, but isn't very well documented (yet), and very shortly at [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) which kinda knocked me off with its "doing everything a bit different".

So please, no "i've read about this" or "let me google that for you" answers :) - I'd like one framework per post, with reasons why I should look at it.

Comment: What's wrong with the post you mention?

Comment: @OscarRyz: Most answers over there just list the frameworks, without actually telling us why one is better than the other, or why it is interesting.