# How do I get started with Scala

Tags: scala, web-deployment

Are there any good resources to get started with Scala web development? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?

I have checked https://www.scala-lang.org/ and it is a not good starting point for scala web development.

Comment: Have a look at something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/what-scala-web-frameworks-are-available, or search for "Scala web framework".

Comment: surprised they don't mention scala.js for frontend on that post

Comment: Not particular about `Scala` *web-development* but for general **Functional Programming** & `Scala` concepts you can take [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1) course.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to backend, you could start from learning some frameworks like play or akka on which play is actually based(there are plenty of books about them), but if you mean frontend by "web development", there is also scala.js, but I would not recommend it to you since it has rather poor community and there is no many people that actually use it. If you are interested in some database connection then I recommend reading smth about slick.